# How do I extract the last 4 digits of numerical value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I extract the last for digits from a number in Microsoft SQL Server? For example `'6789'` from a number like `'123456789'`.

I just want to keep the last 4 numbers.

Comment: . . I added the data base tag based on your question.  When asking a SQL question, you should tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Is that value really a number (integer or floating point datatype) or a string (varchar) consisting of only digits? These require different operations to get the last 4 digits

Answer (score 3):

If you are starting with a number, you are asking for the [modulo operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).  This generally has one of two syntaxes.  SQL Server uses:

```
select col % 10000
```

An alternative syntax in other databases is:

```
select mod(col, 10000)
```

Comment: @Christopher Take note, however, that `123450000 % 10000` will return just `0` instead of `0000` as you're using numeric operations.

Answer (score 2):

You can use right function, example for you:

```
select right('123456789',4)
```

Answer (score 1):

One more approach using SUBSTRING.

```sql
DECLARE @table table(a varchar(30))
insert into @table
values ('12345678')

SELECT SUBSTRING(a,len(a) - 3, 4) from @table
```

> 5678